# echo HTML not being outputted

Tags: php, html, echo

I have this PHP code:

```
    <nav><ul>
        <?php

if( (isset($_SESSION['user_role']) ) && (false != $_SESSION['user_role']) )
{
    if( '2' == $_SESSION['user_role'] ) 
    { 
        echo "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>";
    } 

    elseif ('3' == $_SESSION['user_role'] ) 
    { 
        echo "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>Admin</a></li>";
    } 


}


?>
    <ul></nav>
```

For some reason the html code that is being echoed out is not displaying when I run the php file on the browser.

Any suggestions please?

This is where I set my session variable:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","darrenvellaedp2") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

                $result = "SELECT userRoleID FROM tbl_users WHERE userRoleID = 2" or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

                $res = $con->query($result);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                    $UserRoleID = $row['userRoleID'];

                    $_SESSION['user_role'] = $UserRoleID;
                }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION['user_role']`?

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['user_role'])` should probably give you your answer.

Comment: I can  confirm that it's 2

Comment: As @Joe commented maybe the value in $_SESSION['user_role'] is not set and that the reason you don't see anythin. Try adding an else to the first if. Something like: `if( (isset($_SESSION['user_role']) ) && (false != $_SESSION['user_role']) ) { //code } else {echo 'session is not set' }`

Comment: Are both code segments you shared in the same file? Or are they accessed in separate HTTP requests? The reason I ask is because every HTTP request that accesses the $_SESSION var must start with `session_start()`.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles no they are not in the same file. The problem is that when I add another session_start() I get error: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WSSA1S1\new\pagetemplateLOGINSEC.php on line 4

Comment: So maybe the other file is missing session_start.

Comment: I tried adding session_start() at every php I can think of and stil get the error A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WSSA1S1\new\pagetemplateLOGINSEC.php on line 4

Answer (score 4):

If no output is being generated, then it means your first conditional `IF` statement is failing. I.e.:

```
if( (isset($_SESSION['user_role']) ) && (false != $_SESSION['user_role']) )
```

You should add a `var_dump($_SESSION['user_role'])` to check the session data is there.

P.s. did you remember to add `session_start();` at the beginning of this script? i.e..

```
<?php

// start php session
session_start();

?>
<nav><ul>

    // rest of your code
```

Comment: **NOTE:** `session_start()` needs to come before HTML

Comment: Adding a session start will output this error 
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WSSA1S1\new\pagetemplateLOGINSEC.php on line 4

Comment: Adding a var_dump did not change anything @Latheesan Kanes maybe im not implementing it right. Here is how I implemented it: if( '2' == var_dump($_SESSION['user_role']) ) just like you said

Comment: @user3136576 - that's really not what Latheesan Kanes was saying. Look at the docs for how to use it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: sorry I posted the answer quickly without checking. Yes session_start comes before any html output starts. answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First page

```
<?php
session_start();   

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","darrenvellaedp2") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

                    $result = "SELECT userRoleID FROM tbl_users WHERE userRoleID = 2" or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

                    $res = $con->query($result);

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                        $UserRoleID = $row['userRoleID'];

                        $_SESSION['user_role'] = $UserRoleID;
                    }
?>
```

second page

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<nav><ul>
<?php

if( (isset($_SESSION['user_role']) ) && (false != $_SESSION['user_role']) )
{
    if( '2' == $_SESSION['user_role'] ) 
    { 
        echo "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>";
    } 

    elseif ('3' == $_SESSION['user_role'] ) 
    { 
        echo "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>Admin</a></li>";
    } 


}


?>
    </ul></nav>
```

Comment: I forgot to copy it here. But it's there in my actual php file. Sorry

Comment: print the value of $_SESSION. print_r($_SESSION); before the if statement starting

Comment: Where should I see the value? Because when I add print_r and refresh the page nothing changes..

Comment: still nothing changes

Comment: Have you added session_start(); at the top of the php file where connection is establishing?

Comment: yes I did add it. It's exactly like the code you posted above.

Comment: can you add echo $UserRoleID; inside the while loop?

Comment: please echo $_SESSION['user_role]; inside the while loop

Comment: again I'm getting value of 2

Comment: the first block of code what you have pasted above is the continuation of the second block of code or a different page?

Comment: it's in a different page

Comment: so in the first block of code you have to add <?php session_start(); ?> as the first line and try.

Answer (score 0):

Next, put the conditional session_status in the first code segment you shared:

```
<?php

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","darrenvellaedp2") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
$sql = "SELECT userRoleID FROM tbl_users WHERE userRoleID = 2";
$res = $con->query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$_SESSION['user_role'] = $row['userRoleID'];

?>
```

And `print_r` in the second:

```
<nav><ul>

<?php

print 'user_role: ';
print_r($_SESSION['user_role']);

if( (isset($_SESSION['user_role']) ) && (false != $_SESSION['user_role']) )
{
    if( '2' == $_SESSION['user_role'] ) 
    { 
        echo "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>";
    } 

    elseif ('3' == $_SESSION['user_role'] ) 
    { 
        echo "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='loginpage.php'>Login</a></li>";
        echo "<li><a href='#'>Admin</a></li>";
    } 
}

?>
</ul></nav>
```

And report back what `user_role:` outputs.

Comment: The same thing is happening @bloodyKnuckles no html is being outputted and I'm getting error: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: I'm suggesting you run this file independent of any other files, to narrow down the problem. Do you know how this file is getting wrapped in some other file? If you don't, I added a session conditional to hopefully work around that problem.

Comment: the html is being outputted

Comment: So, then, we need to see the bigger picture of how you have your system setup. What are all the files involved in outputting your navigation scheme?

Comment: that is the only php file involved with my naviagation scehem. Although I'm using this php file in other pages with the include() .